# Can users access the whole model object properties i am passing to my view, even if i am not generating HTML for some properties

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, security, razor

I am working on an asp.net mvc-4 web application... and i have the following model class:-

```
public partial class SOrder
        {

            public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
            public int CustomerID { get; set; }
            public int OrderStatusID { get; set; }
            public int OrderTypeID { get; set; }
            public int CommissionTypeID { get; set; }
            public string StageNumber { get; set; }
            public string ServiceName { get; set; }
            public string ServiceDescription { get; set; }
}
```

now inside my edit/details views i want to hide certain fields from users.. currently i am passing the whole Model to the view , then i am using If statements to check for the `Model.StageNumber` value and show/hide related fields accordingly as follow:-

```
@model S.Models.SOrder
  @{
      ViewBag.Title = "Edit Order";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerID, (SelectList)ViewBag.Customers, "Choose...") 
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerID)
   <br />
    <span class="f">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClientManagerID)</span> 


 //code goes here..   

     if (Model!=null && Model.StageNumber >= 2)
    {
            <div>
    <span class="f"> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AssetID) </span> 
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AssetID) 
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AssetID)
</div>
    .....
    }
```

so for example in the above code,  i am checking if the `Model.StageNumber >=2` to show the AssetID.. so not sure if doing so will prevent users from hacking my system in the following 2 scenarios:-

1. since i am passing the whole Model to the view.. can users (using tools such as fiddler) view the whole model properties ? let say the current stage number =1 ,, can they view the AssetID ?
2. can users modify the Model.StageNumber at the view level,, and then see the AssetID value?

can anyone adivce if my approach is valid ?or it will suffer from weak security and will allow users to easily view the field values and bypass my If checks inside the view ? or asp.net mvc will not expose the Model object properties passed to the view , unless i am explicitly showing the properties using DisplayFor,EditorFor, or other methods ?

Answer (score 1):

Users can't modify or access the model values -- that is rendered to HTML on the server before it is sent to their browsers. If you don't make use of the model property then it won't be sent over the wire.

Users can alter form values posted to your server (or construct a request from scratch). So you still need to **validate all user input** in your controller action that handles the form submission.

In other words, they can't see or manipulate `Model.StageNumber` to alter `Model.AssetID`. But they can modify the form value directly `<input name="AssetID" value="1234" />` before it is sent back to your application.

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply. I am aware that they can PostBack the value, that why inside my Post edit action method i will set any un-realted fields to be null. so if users try to hack the system by sending assetid when the stage =1, then my post edit action method will set the assetid to be equal to null

Comment: .But let say i am rendering the stage number inside the view as follow @Html.HiddenFor(a=>a.StageNumer) (although i am not doing so), so do you mean in this case hackers can modify the @Html.HiddenFor(a=>a.StageNumber) to be equal to 2 at the view level ,,, and then they will be able to view the assetid ??? or this it is not possible to modify the model properties at the view level ?

Comment: A malicious user can make a request without using your web page to send anything to your server. But they don't even need to do that much work: just right-click-inspect your form on the rendered view and plug whatever values you want into it. Editing the model (`a.StageNumber`) is a moot point because that has already rendered to HTML on the server and won't execute again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want certain fields read only to user you can do that by changing `@EditorFor` to `@DisplayFor` by doing this user will only able to see those fields but can't change directly. If those field are required it will give you error validation message and to get rid of that you need to use `@hiddenFor` in you code.

Now, with this change your code is still hack-able using fiddler tool.To avoid that you will need to modify your controller where it is binding your data to object.

use UpdateModel's 4th overloded version where you can specify properties which will get updated explicitly.

for example

```
UpdateModel(employee, new string[]{"ID","Gender","City","BirthDate"});
```

here, employee is object that is binding data and ID,Gender,City,Birthdate are fields which will only get updated/Modified

so by doing this your both problems will get solved : Nobody will able to change data using fiddler tool and user will also not able to change data.

Source Video : 
1st video to know how fiddler changes data

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfBvS-VOZFw

2nd Video to know how to prevent that changes

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T__S4GmQsYs

Comment: Is your problem solved or not ? just wanted to know that answer was helpful or not ?